# TypeScript: How to refine a type where one of it's properties is probably null

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to understand how to write a function that would refine my type and then return it.

It works for the passed object itself and within the function body but not outside. Furthermore what I find odd is that even if it works within the body of the function, it stops working on the return statement itself.

My expectation would be that TypeScript correctly returns a refined / narrowed down type, checked properties included not just the main object.

What am I doing wrong? Does TypeScript require more help, maybe some generic return type?

**Example:**

```
 
type Referrer = { id: string }

type User = {
    id: string;
    referrer: Referrer | null;
} | null;


function checkUserHasReferrer(user: User) {
  if (!user) {
      throw Error('No User');
  }

  if (!user.referrer) {
    console.log(user.referrer) // referrer correctly narrowed to `referrer: null`
    throw Error('No Referrer');
  }
  const referrer = user.referrer; // referrer correctly narrowed to `referrer: Referrer`
  console.log(user.referrer).     // same here, `referrer: Referrer`
  

  return user; // <- Here however it's back to `referrer: Referrer | null`
}


let initialUser: User = null;
const user = checkUserHasReferrer(initialUser);
console.log(user.id);           // <-- knows User is not `null`
console.log(user.referrer.id);  // However it doesn't know referrer is not `null`
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=30&ssc=82&pln=27&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgzhATlAvFA3gKAJAEsAmAXFHMIrgHYDmA3DohAGZIOLEBKTLSUAPlBQCuAG2F0AvnwEixmTKEhROzRK1QYoBYqXLUo4uZmERgmirmC4AhsPhJid5GiGi6mRoIoBjSwHsKUF4AFhBeANaOABJWcMrciAAUgghssCkAlBiYUJqMUAkAhMlImVjYOcBBiL4A7lAAoqq+iQDkAHK+aUgt6XQ5Btm5+UUpAHQMKqylgzle-nC+xqPCvlRJYxPxmQD021Cbqjxzhz7CIAJWTTUQ+FDAnQAGB6zELsIPM3dVtQ1NrR1KLiHRA9Pr6QZzCikfZAtRoYqIcawpA0KC7GGTI7NBinc4US7Va63e5QJ7I1JxYEfWbzRYQZardZIJGYxC9HI5dFwKwAW2gIQYABpSc97IDWdSoHIcgxgIJEAEEaj0QAeAC0UEiSH5tQgADceBYWnAoAAjKzhO6PUUU8lSN4fAaQ6EI9TBUIRFLRWLkhKUCzWWwZZV7dUagCSUAgAA9ID4oAiWfErWboA9KawHsKgrqDchcCayayOHb+A65M66Qy1omCOyOQ2Oaq1RqwhRaibHJoTe3TA9y5WlisaxtyaM66i0XtIrnDaZ8L4IHAKC1TG2fjbuwJfH3y0A)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [assertion functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions)

```js
type Referrer = { id: string }

type User = {
  id: string;
  referrer: Referrer | null;
}



function notNull(user: unknown): asserts  user {
  if (!user) {
    throw Error('No User');
  }
}

declare const user: User | null


notNull(user)
notNull(user.referrer)

console.log(user.id);
console.log(user.referrer.id);  // ok
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/NdYknm)

When you need to throw an error in TypeScript, usually such function is a good candidate to be `assertion function`

---

Or, you can use [custom typeguard functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards)

```js
type Referrer = { id: string }

type User = {
  id: string;
  referrer: Referrer | null;
}

const isValidUser = (user: User | null): user is User & { referrer: Referrer } =>
  Boolean(user && user.referrer)

declare const user: User

if (isValidUser(user)) {
  console.log(user.id);
  console.log(user.referrer.id);  // ok
}
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/N7yLEW)

Answer (score 2):

This is currently a known limitation of TypeScript. See [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42384) or [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/50651). TypeScript does correctly *narrow* the type of the property but the type of the parent is *not* modified, so it remains just `User`.

One possible workaround without type assertions would be to *spread* the object when returning it.

```
return {
    ...user,
    referrer
};
```

This changes the return type of the function to

```
{
    referrer: Referrer;
    id: string;
}
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgzhATlAvFA3gKAJAEsAmAXFHMIrgHYDmA3DohAGZIOLEBKTLSUAPlBQCuAG2F0AvnwEixmTKEhROzRK1QYoBYqXLUo4uZmERgmirmC4AhsPhJid5GiGi6mRoIoBjSwHsKUF4AFhBeANaOABJWcMrciAAUgghssCkAlBiYUJqMUAkAhMlImVjYOcBBiL4A7lAAoqq+iQDkAHK+aUgt6XQ5Btm5+UUpAHQMKqylgzle-nC+xqPCvlRJYxPxmQD021Cbqjxzhz7CIAJWTTUQ+FDAnQAGB6zELsIPM3dVtQ1NrR1KLiHRA9Pr6QZzCikfZAtRoYqIcawpA0KC7GGTI7NBinc4US7Va63e5QJ7I1JxYEfWbzRYQZardZIJGYxC9HI5dFwKwAW2gIQYABpSc97IDWdSoHIcgxgIJEAEsByoKNVQjBZ9RYhBuJUeiADwAWigkSQ-NqEAAbjwLC04FAAEZWcJ3R5ajjkqRvD4DSHQhHqYKhCIpaKxckJSgWay2DJ6vZG40ASSgEAAHpAfFAESz4q7HdAHpTWA9hUELdbkLh7WTWR7WV6ZB9MH66Qy1jmCOzlT20QnDcawhRavbHJp7cPTA9vS3aUsVh2NuTRl3UX2TRWbaZ8L4IHAKC1TEOflrxwJfFOZ0A)

Comment: But in your playground, you pass `intialUser` to your function which actually is `null`, and yet you are able to access `user.id`

Comment: Huh. I am not the OP and apparently I did not read the question quite as clearly as I should have. I would have thought we should have a typescript error if we do pass `null` to the function. It seems the OP would be fine with this. Captain's answer does have that advantage though.

Comment: I wasn't aware it is a TypeScript limitation. Your first example would definitely work however I ended up going for a custom typeguard outside my function because that can be a more generic. Either way, thank you